# Detect spi device from another driver

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, spi

I have a Freescale imx.6q (arm) based board.
Hardware is configured with devicetree.

It had a change major incompatible change to timings and voltage for an onboard fpga, but these changes are invisible to the kernel. 
The EE's tell us we shouldn't load the old fpga firmware for fear of damaging it. I would like to support both hardware from the same code (It is already causing confusion)

The solution I have thought of is this:
There are several new spi temperature sensors on the board. If I can read from one of those devices, I can infer that I need the new firmware.

How can I (in one driver) grab an spi device and then release it?
I suspect that I might be able to do something like this with device tree,
But I don't want to make the device unavailable.

Any ideas or examples of something like this being done?

Comment: Er, the whole point of DT is to describe the hardware; if the hardware is different, you have a perfect way to describe it differently. Adding a `foo,device-rev2` binding to the driver which already supports `foo,device` is a lot saner than doing tricks with random other devices, no?

Comment: I get what you are saying. But the DT resides on an SD card, not on the actual hardware, so it can't be trusted. I need to probe the hardware.

Comment: But SPI is only a wire protocol - I don't see how the kernel's going to know anything about these other new devices without an updated DT which says that they exist and where to find them ;)

Comment: Take a look at [Linux SPI documents](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spi/spi-summary) and [SO questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-kernel+spi).  There are also [**iMx6 examples of SPI devices**](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6qdl.dtsi?id=refs/tags/v4.4-rc1); look for *spi#* in the imx.6q DTS board files.  Obviously, it is possible.  Also, you could do this in the boot loader.  Attempt something and you will have a better question.  Probably you could do this in user mode (as well as supply FPGA binary).

Comment: For instance, [read data from SPI in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807471/how-to-read-data-from-a-serial-spi-connection-in-c) is a way to read the temperature sensor from user space.  Then conditionally supply old/new FPGA binary to some FPGA loading device, if the FPGA doesn't need to be loaded immediately (future proof for more FPGA versions).  If it does, then the boot loader is probably the place to do this.  You might also ask hardware to provide traces for optional pull-up/down on normal outputs and then have the BOM populated with different resisters based on the HW version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT (answer the question)
To detect use an SPI device from another driver use a reference to the device in the devicetree structure.

Short answer: add a reference to the spi device in your devices dts entry.

Slightly longer answer:
When adding spi to another device driver, you are effectively adding a subdevice, which may want its own driver. I have an FPGA which loads its firmware over (something close enough to be considered) SPI. I started with the idea of just treating the spi device as part of the larger driver, but the more work went into it, the more obvious it was that it is its own device, with a purpose and function that is distinct from the rest of the driver. I separated that code into its own driver.
Now instead of a reference to an SPI device, my driver just has a reference to an FPGA Manager device.

See line 98, 370 of https://github.com/d4ddi0/linux/blob/v4.12evi/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6q-evi.dts

and 
make sure the spi driver is loaded before your driver completes loading

My original answer to my question (for historical purposes):

What I ended up doing was using different devicetree files. The difference is know at initial install time (based on the serial number). The bootloader knows which dts filename to load.

There are multiple FPGA firmware versions and the right one is chosen based on the description in the dts.

This way, I can still update the driver and/or dts without breakage.

This works well in practice even though it does not detect anything at runtime.

One problem still exists, if I take an SD card from a new revision, and put it into an old one, the incorrect firmware will be loaded. To really solve this last problem, we've talked about adding an EEPROM to uniquely identify the hardware revision on future boards.

Answer (score 1):

After reading question i think your concern is how to add software support for more than one hardware.
If that is the case i think we can write two drivers supporting both hardware's with different configuration such as irq, voltage, register set etc.
So i will enable both drivers in Makefile and config file.
So at the time of boot when probe of drivers gets called we can check the hardware id by using spi_read command from driver.

If hardware id matches then driver probe gets successful and driver can be used to interact with hardware.
If spi_read fails then driver probe itself will fail.
I think this will do the trick.