# Communication with mbed using C

Tags: c, mbed

How can I communicate with an mbed LPC1768 using C without using a terminal emulator like minicom or teraterm?

For example if I send an integer from my C code than that led should be turned on.

How can I do this?

Comment: (@Dinosaur: code formatting is for _code_. Not for brand names or otherwise plain English. Please don't abuse it.)

Answer (score 0):

Without reading user manual or datasheet you can't do any thing to your board. So just go through it then follow below link for demo application LPC1768 board

1.[NXP LPC1768 ARM Cortex-M3 Red Suite Demo](http://www.freertos.org/LPC1768_RedSuite.html)

2.[LPC1768 ARM Cortex-M3 CrossWorks Demo](http://www.freertos.org/LPC1768_CrossWorks.html)

3.[mbed](https://mbed.org/users/nxpfan/notebook/mbed-led-blink-code-on-lpcxpresso-lpc1768/)

4.[At github](https://github.com/ajhc/demo-cortex-m3/blob/master/mbed-nxp-lpc1768/samples/Blink/main.c)

Comment: sorry.. i could not understand this... can you give a simpler example? I was able to communicate with mbed by minicom but I want to do it using C code

Comment: @user3318922 without interface it's not possible,first you connect you r board with serial then write c code which accept your serial data and according serial data you can on/off LED.For on/off LED you must know GPIO pin for set. So first go trough data sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux or osx check out the following answer:

[How do I read data from serial port in Linux using C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600275/how-do-i-read-data-from-serial-port-in-linux-using-c)

You can check your `/dev` folder and look for a file that is created when you plug your mBed. The file name would be something like `/dev/ttyS0`. That file represents the communication port, you can read/write that file to receive/send data over serial port.

If you want a cross platform solution try RxTx library for Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this library](https://developer.mbed.org/users/sam_grove/code/BufferedSerial/#a0d37088b405)

what it does, is that it initialize UART port which is connected to the debugger on your board and use it as serial input output. so with any hyper terminal of your choice, you can write code to do something if you send certain string of characters or just use original `printf` when something happens. and it will be printed on your PC screen.