# Communicating between C & Arduino

Tags: android, c, linux, serial-communication

I have battled this issue for a while now and it is driving me nuts:

I am trying to communicate very simply with an Arduino Mega 2560 (via USB as a serial device) from pc running Linux (Knoppix on a usb-dok) when all I am trying to accomplish at this stage is that for each number sent by the laptop to the Arduino, a 'stobe' signal will switch for High to Low or the other way around, and i use this strobe to light turn an LED on and off.

pc side C code:

```css
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
 FILE * Device = NULL;
 int counter = 0;
 
 Device = fopen("/dev/ttyACM0", "w+");
 if(Device == NULL)
 {
  printf("could not open Device\n");
  return -1;
 }

 while (counter < 10)
 {
  fprintf(Device, "%d\n", counter);
  printf("Sent to Device: %d\n", counter);
  counter++;
  sleep(2);
 }

 fclose(Device);

return 0;
}
```

Arduino code:

```css
int cnt = 0;
int strobe = 0;
int num;
int ValidInput = 0;

char intBuffer[12];
String intData = "";
int delimiter = (int) '\n';

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
}

int input;

void loop()
{
  while(num = Serial.available())
  {
    delay(5);
//  Serial.println(num);
    int ch = Serial.read();
    if(ch == delimiter)
    {
     ValidInput = 1;
     break;
    }
     else
    {
      intData += (char) ch;
    }
  }
  int intLen = intData.length() + 1;
  intData.toCharArray(intBuffer, intLen);
  intData = "";
  int i = atoi(intBuffer);
  
  if(ValidInput)
  {
      if(i == 0)
      {
       strobe = 0;
       Serial.print("Initializing strobe");
      }
      else
      {
       strobe = !strobe;
      }
      
      digitalWrite(3, (strobe) ? HIGH : LOW);
      Serial.println(i);
      ValidInput = 0;
  }
}
```

The problems I am having:

1. Not sure if fopen is the correct way to communicate with a serial device in Linux, and if so in which mode?
2. This is the main issue - I am experiencing non-deterministic behavior:
   if i run this code right before opening the Arduino editor's 'Serial monitor' it doesn't work as I explained above, instead - it will turn the LED on and then off right away, for each incoming new number.
   but once I open the 'Serial monitor' it would act as I want it to - changing the LED's state for each new incoming number.

I am thinking this has something to do with the Arduino's reset or something of that sort.

I looked in many threads here and other forums and couldn't find any solution to this problem.

I'd really appreciate your insight.

Comment: Your arduino code looks reasonable. Try using http://www.libusb.org/ for the PC side of things.

Comment: @SoundConception - no, libusb is not the logical choice here.  The USB device is handled by the kernel/module USB serial or (in this case) CDC/ACM driver.  Application programs should use the Serial API, which is what the program attempts to do.  The most obvious thing missing (and precisely correlated with the observed problem) is port configuration, and that typically requires a file descriptor from open() rather than a stream from fopen().

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the arduino side looks ok. On the Linux side you need to do some reasearch since the serial communication on posix systems is a little bit more complicated than only opening a file and writing to it. Please use the linux man pages for termios where you can find information on how to setup the communication port parameters and use this document http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/ for actually learning how to put everything altogether. The serial programming howto will guide you through the process of setting up a port, learning how to control it and learn how to accept input from multiple sources. Also in order to access successfully the serial port from an unprivileged account, you might need to add that user (your user) to a specific group (dialout group in Ubuntu and Fedora). You can search on Google about serial port access under linux and you can fine a lot of code samples ready for you to integrate in your application. You can find an excellent reference and a full documented implementation at the bottom of this thread , also on SO [How do I read data from serial port in Linux using C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600275/how-do-i-read-data-from-serial-port-in-linux-using-c)

Answer (score 0):

A simple fopen doesn't setup any of the serial ports communication parameters.  You need to set the baud rate, number of bits, parity, and number of stop bits. And, if you want to use the linux line discipline or not.  The termio structure is used to do this.

There are a couple good tutorial on how to use serial between linux and arduinos.

http://chrisheydrick.com/2012/06/12/how-to-read-serial-data-from-an-arduino-in-linux-with-c-part-1/

http://todbot.com/blog/2006/12/06/arduino-serial-c-code-to-talk-to-arduino/