# How to read serial data from in Linux with C

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I'm trying to write some code to read data from a serial port continuously in a loop and write it to a file. I'm a beginner programmer.

I gather I can use `fopen()` to open a "file" to the serial port, which is what this code does.

My question is how would you read it continuously and write it to a file. The baud rate is 115200 and there are line feeds and carriage returns. How do you specify this parameters?

```
  FILE *fp = fopen("/dev/ttyUSB1", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        perror("open failed");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        // read from file

    }
```

If I open the serial port with minicom this is what the data looks like:

```
Starting Contiki-1cb08a4
With DriverLib v0.44336
TI SmartRF06EB + CC26xx EM
 Net: sicslowpan
 MAC: TSCH2
 RDC: nordc
 RF: Channel 25
[node] id=0, role=6ln
Starting Contiki-1cb08a4
With DriverLib v0.44336
TI SmartRF06EB + CC26xx EM
 Net: sicslowpan
 MAC: TSCH2
 RDC: nordc
 RF: Channel 25
[node] id=0, role=6ln
```

Comment: You might like to [have look here](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+read+from+serial+port+under+linux+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600275/how-do-i-read-data-from-serial-port-in-linux-using-c

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108932/linux-c-serial-port-reading-writing

Comment: https://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html